# (Python) For Loop Doesn't Iterate Over All Lines in Large Text File

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a program to clean some temporal data. The goal of the program is to take two files, which contain different pieces of information about the same time steps, and combine those pieces of information.

The first part of the program turns one file into a binary search tree. The second part looks at each line of the first file, extracts the needed data, and searches the BST for data at the same timestep.

The issue I have is, using a print statement, I can tell the for loops end after reading only 3-4k lines of text, when there are actually about 200k. Furthermore, the program doesn't even begin the second for loop. **The program actually works fine for smaller text files** but that's not what I need it for.

Below is a shortened version of my code. Elapsed is defined but not included.

```
setrecursionlimit(15000)

def extract_bid_ask(bid_file, ask_file):

labels = []
fvecs = []
ask_bst = bst.BinarySearchTree()

with open(ask_file) as file:
    for line in reversed(list(file)):

        row = line.split(',')

        if float(row[2]) != -1.0:
            ask_bst.put(elapsed, [float(row[2]), float(row[5])])


with open(bid_file) as file:
    for line in file:

        row = line.split(',')

        if float(row[2]) != -1.0:           
            asks = ask_bst.get(elapsed)

            if asks is not None:
                fvecs.append([elapsed, float(row[2]), float(row[5]), float(asks[0]), float(asks[1])])
                labels.append(int(row[0]))
```

Comment: The key you're using in your BST is always `elapsed`, which isn't set anywhere in the code you posted... either you left out an absolutely critical part of the code, or you're only storing one item in the tree!  Also, what BST implementation are you using?  It looks like there are dozens online...

Comment: @jasonharper Ah, sorry about that. For readability, I removed some code, including how `elapsed` was defined. As I mentioned, this code works for small text files, so I think it has to do with the number of iterations. The BST implementation used [link](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Trees/SearchTreeImplementation.html). I can post the full code if you want but it's a bit messier. Right now I'm just working with an alternate approach.